# Angular dynamic value from child to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a reusable table which is table-multi-sort.component component , deals-approval.component is one example that uses the reusable table component.

How do we let and make the parent component only show the alert info message if this.totalDealsForApproval from child component is > 0 ? , how to dynamically make it possible in angular? Thank you for any ideas and solutions.

#this code on table-multi-sort.component should be dynamic including the message based on the child component.

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="alertInfo" >
      <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>This deal was sent to approval and waiting for approval.
    </div>
  </div>
```

#deals-approval.component html code

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <div>
        <app-table-multi-sort (dataServiceEvent)="dataForApprovalServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions"
            [tableData]="data"></app-table-multi-sort>
    </div>
</div>
```

##deals-approval.component ts code

```
export class DealsApprovalComponent implements OnInit {
  transactionSubscripion: Subscription;
  @ViewChild(TableMultiSortComponent, { static: true }) tableMultiSortComponent: TableMultiSortComponent;
  tableOptions: any;
  @Input() transaction: any;
  @Input() dataTest: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  totalDeals : number;
  accountId: any;
  data: any;
  searchInput: string;
  table: any;
  totalDealsForApproval = 0;
  constructor(
    private dealService: DealService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private trasactionService: TransactionService
    
  ) {
    this.transactionSubscripion =
      this.trasactionService.transactionEvent$.subscribe(
        (data) => {
          if (data) {
            switch (data['operation']) {
              case 'transaction/update':
                this.table.pageIndex = 0;
                this.table.pageSize = 10;
                this._pageEventDealsForApprovalList();
                break;
            }
          }
        },
        (error) => {}
      );
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const currentAccountDetails = localStorage.getItem('currAcct') as any;
    if (currentAccountDetails) {
      this.accountId = JSON.parse(currentAccountDetails).accountId;
    }

    this.tableOptions = {
      columns:[
        {id:'name',name:'Deal Name',subId:'type', subtitle:'Deal Type'},
        {id:'annualRentProposed',name:'Annual Rent (Proposed)', subId: 'annualRentCurrent', subtitle:'Annual Rent (Proposed)'},
        {id:'firmTermRemain',name:'Firm Term Remaining', subId: 'firmTermAdded', subtitle:'(Current)'},
        {id:'maxTerm',name:'Max Available Term'},
        {id:'cash',name:'Cash Contribution'},
      ]
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.transactionSubscripion) this.transactionSubscripion.unsubscribe();
  }
  dataForApprovalServiceEvent(item) {
    this.table = item;
    if(this.table) {
      this._pageEventDealsForApprovalList();
    }
  }

  private _pageEventDealsForApprovalList() {
    this.searchInput = '';
    const status = 'ForApproval'
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.table.data = res.items;
        this.table.hasAlertInfo = true;
        this.totalDealsForApproval = res.items.length;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.trasactionService.transactionEvent.next({
            sendData: this.totalDealsForApproval,
            operation: 'transaction/update/count'
          });
        }, 0);  
      }, (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err)
);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIMpv.png)

#html code table-multi-sort.component.ts

```
<mat-card *ngIf="table !== undefined">
  <div style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="alertInfo" >
      <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>This deal was sent to approval and waiting for approval.
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="table.dataSource" matMultiSort (matSortChange)="table.onSortEvent()"> 
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of table.columns" [matColumnDef]="column.id">
      <mat-header-cell class="table-multi-sort-header" *matHeaderCellDef [mat-multi-sort-header]="column.id"> 
        <div>{{column.name}}</div> 
        <div class="sub-text">{{getColumnSubtitle(column.id)}}</div>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <ng-container *ngIf="column.id !== 'action'; then col; else actionCol"></ng-container>
          <ng-template #col>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-default [cellData]="row" [id]="column.id" [subId]="getColumnSubId(column.id)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-default>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #actionCol>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-action [rowData]="row" [actions]="getActions(column.id)" (actionClickEvent)="clickTableAction($event,row)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-action>
          </ng-template>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="table.displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let item; columns: table.displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table> 
  <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="isLoading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</mat-card>
```

#table-multi-sort.component ts code

```
export class TableMultiSortComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() tableOptions:any;
  @Input() tableData:any = [];
  @Input() isClientSide:boolean = false;
  @Input() isLoading: boolean = false;
  @Output() tableActionsEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() dataServiceEvent = new EventEmitter<any>() ;
  @ViewChild(MatMultiSort, { static: false }) sort: MatMultiSort;
  hasInfoMessage: boolean;
  tableConfig: any = TABLE_MULTI_SORT_OPTIONS.DEFAULT;
  table:TableData<any>;
  displayedColumns: any;
  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.initTableMultiSort();
  }

  initTableMultiSort() {
    this.tableConfig = {
      ...this.tableConfig,
      ...this.tableOptions
    }
    
    this.table = new TableData<any>(this.tableConfig.columns,this.tableConfig.sortParams);
    this.table.pageSize = this.tableConfig.pageSize;
    this.table.pageIndex = this.tableConfig.pageIndex;
    this.table.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.table.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.isClientSide);
      this.getData();
    },0);
  }
  getData(){
    this.table.totalElements = 1;
    this.table.pageIndex = 0;
    this.table.pageSize = 10;
    this.table.data = this.tableData;

    if(this.dataServiceEvent) {
      this.dataServiceEvent.emit(this.table);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should be able to bind a function to one of the EventEmitters (or a new one if needed) and emit the currently selected ones from there when a selection has changed. It seems you only emit dataServiceEvent currently when table sorting or page actions occur which doesn't seem to fit the name. Is that what you want?

I think in general it looks like you are passing too much stuff around and could do with simplifying. Any chance you could get a minimum example on stackblitz that would help with giving feedback.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-js1nsf?file=src/app/deals-approval/deals-approval.component.ts

Comment: What I want Sir is that the alert info of the table should be dynamic and the data or the message of the alert info should be coming from deals-approval.component _pageEventDealsForApprovalList

Comment: text error message. it shpuld be available for search engine